# Onclick with Form Submit in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i want to do something like,when i click on Submit Button, form should be submitted even few fields are blank,but message should print on top of the page that "these Fields are pending to save" but i want to ptint it without validation so i have done something like this

```
echo form_submit('tax', 'Save & Continue',"class='btn-lg-blk btn-orange'",'onclick="return DisplayMessages();" ');
```

in this code, form can submit but onclick is not working
any suggestion how can i develop this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to submit your form. Your function should be like this-

```
function DisplayMessages(){
   if(field1=="" || field2==""){
     //print your message here
     $("#element_id").text('These Fields are pending to save');
  }
  //post your form using ajax
  $.post( "http://yourdomain.com/controller/function", $("#form_id").serialize())
   .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
  return false;
}
```

This way your message will show wherever you want and your form will be submitted.

Comment: @RKinfotech You need to replace the #element_id with your own html element id(where you are displaying message) in this line $("#element_id").text('These Fields are pending to save')

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
<?php
$form_attr  =
array(
  'name'    =>  'formname',
  "id"    =>  "formid",
  'method'  =>  'post',
  'onsubmit' => 'return DisplayMessages()',
  'class'     =>  "form-horizontal",
  'role'  =>'form'
  );

echo form_open("controller/method",$form_attr);

?>
```

Comment: @RKinfotech then what happned?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `form_submit` use **form_button** like as follow :

```
<?php

    $data = array(
    'name' => 'tax',
    'id' => 'button',
    'type' => 'button',
    'content' => 'Save & Continue',
    'class'=>'btn-lg-blk btn-orange',
    'onclick'=>'return DisplayMessages(this);'    
);

echo form_button($data);

    ?>
```

it will create an element as follow :

```
<button onclick="return DisplayMessages(this);" class="btn-lg-blk btn-orange" id="button" type="button" name="tax">Save &amp; Continue</button>
```

and on `DisplayMessages()` function write the manual java script from submit ion code  :

```
   function DisplayMessages(element)
    {
      $(element).closest("form").submit();
    }
```

Comment: many thnx for solution..now onclick works but i want to do both things togather..like form should submit in database and also message should print on the top of the same page..with the use of Button i can print the message but am i able to submit data in DB?